# solrj Error from server invalid number

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm trying to write some data from my java application to solr using solrj.
I can query the solr server fine, but whenever I try to write some data to the server I get an error of invalid number, even when I'm writing a string to a string field.

Sample code to reproduce the error:

```
public class solrdocimport {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException, IOException  {

    SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient("http://192.168.175.136:8983/solr/nsf");
    SolrInputDocument solrDoc = new SolrInputDocument();
        solrDoc.addField("Subject", "Hello", 1.0f);
        client.add(solrDoc);
    }
  }
```

The field "Subject" exists in the schema and it is defined as a String field, however the error I get is invalid number?

I've search around an cannot find anything in relation to this error. Does anyone know how to I can write to the solr server?

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace of exception?

Comment: Thanks, link to the stack trace: http://pastebin.com/ZwWRpXQh

Comment: In stack trace I see Invalid Number: 31a0f847-2180-46d6-8723-f08fcaa870d0 not clear how this number appear in you document, is it some auto-generated id?

Comment: That's the thing, I am just trying to add a string. There are no numbers anywhere and there are no auto gen ids. Sending any string get's a different number in the response, but the same error of invalid number.

Comment: Can you provide a solr schema?

Comment: The schema is here: http://pastebin.com/m4UPm5kZ It only has a few fields as trying to keep it simple.

Comment: Can you trie to remove random field type I suspected it cause a problem?

Comment: Do you mean remove the entry for random in the schema? I tried that, it did not make a difference. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94824/discussion-between-alexander-kuznetsov-and-a-dev).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds you might have some automatic ID generation in solrconfig.xml and then you changed your id field in schema.xml to be a number. Try changing id back to string, since you are not using it and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution, the schema.xml was not updating on the server and the field for ID was set to int. I recreated another core to get around the issue with the schema not updating and I was able to change the field type for the ID field to string which is working now.